# MongoDB php extension installation failed on MacOs

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, pecl, php-mongodb

I am trying to install the MongoDB PHP Extension in my new MacBook Air M1. I am facing the following error during installation

The command I am using for installation

```sh
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

The error I am facing

```sh
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.9/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:23:10: fatal error: 'pcre2.h' file not found
#include "pcre2.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [php_phongo.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Here is the output of `which php` and `which pecl` command

```sh
aniketmagadum@Anikets-MacBook-Air bin % which php
/opt/homebrew/bin/php
```

```sh
aniketmagadum@Anikets-MacBook-Air bin % which pecl
/opt/homebrew/bin/pecl
```

The PHP Version I am using

```sh
aniketmagadum@Anikets-MacBook-Air bin % php -v
PHP 8.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2021 08:52:24) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.9, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
aniketmagadum@Anikets-MacBook-Air bin %
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to brew install [pcre](https://www.pcre.org) or get it on your system some other way.

Comment: I tried running `brew install pcre` its showing its already installed

Comment: Is pcre [configured](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php) in php.ini?